# how to dynamically allocate fixed char arrays if the size isn’t known at compile time?

Tags: c++

Is this considered to be dynamically allocation on fixed char arrays if the size isn’t known at compile time? My teacher said: "In C++ you can’t allocate a fixed array with a variable length.You have to dynamically allocate fixed arr
 2. List item

ays if the size isn’t known at compile time."  **How to dynamicAally allocate fixed char array if the size is't know n at compile time?** i have tried two examples. i don't know whether is correct or not.

```
#include<iostream>

int main() {    
     std::cout<<"enter the length of string\n";    
     int length; 
     std::cin>>length; 
     char *ch=new char[length];     
     for(int i=0;i<length;i++)     
       std::cin>>ch[i];
     std::cout<<ch;
     delete[]ch;    
     ch=nullptr;//c++11 is accepted 
  }
```

it prints the string without whitespace.I can't print whitespace here. this doesnt show whitespce.

2)

```
int main() {    
    char *ch=new char;
    std::cout<<"enter a string\n";    
    std::cin.getline(ch,255);    
    std::cout<<ch<<'\n'; 
    delete[]ch; 
    ch=nullptr;//c++11 is accepted ## Heading ##  
    std::cout<<" after null pointer:"<<ch; 
 }
```

which is considered to be dynamically allocation on fixed char array if the size is not know at compiletime Or Both of them are not correct?

Comment: `char *ch=new char;` only allocates a single `char`. `std::cin>>ch[i];` skips whitespaces. you can switch that off using `noskipws`.

Comment: This is what a `std::vector` is for.

Comment: You are not null-terminating `ch`.

Comment: Use std::vector or std::string as appropriate. There is no mention of "fixed arrays" in the C++ standard, so if you want to use this term, define it first. How would a fixed array differ from a non-fixed one?

Comment: In your second sample, you use `delete[]` on an object allocated with `new`.  That's a serious error; pair `new` with `delete` and `new[]` with `delete[]` .

Answer (score 1):

The first one is correct regarding "dynamic array allocation in C++".  It looks a bit weird, but it'll do.

Just to make a valid point:

- declaration as `char *` is correct
- allocation via `new char[ size ];` also is correct.  Because this makes your array fixed-size at runtime. (unless you delete and new it again with a different size)

Answer (score 1):

Your 1st example is correct, the 2nd one only allocates memory for a single `char`, which you don't want.

However, If you want a dynamic array with no known compile time length then you should use `std::vector` to make life easier for yourself and your code less error-prone:

```
std::cout<<"enter the length of string\n";    
int length; 
std::cin>>length; 
std::vector<char> ch(length);     
for(int i=0;i<length;i++)     
  std::cin>>ch[i];
ch.push_back('\0');
std::cout<<ch.data();
```